# Emails not being sent using Python smtplib and Gmail: No error message received

Tags: python, smtp

I'm attempting to send emails using a Python script, but despite having no error messages, the emails are not being sent. Below is the relevant code with sensitive information redacted:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Read data from Excel file
excel_file = "C:\\Users\\YourUsername\\Downloads\\AAAAAA.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

# Retrieve email addresses from columns 1 and 2
email_addresses = df.iloc[:, 0].values.flatten()

# Email account credentials
sender_email = "*******@gmail.com"
sender_password = "********"  # 

# Additional details for email content
subject = "Greetings"
body = "Hello, sir"

# Connect to the SMTP server
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)

    # Send the email to each recipient
    for email_address in email_addresses:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = sender_email
        msg['To'] = email_address
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        server.sendmail(sender_email, email_address, msg.as_string())

    # Close the SMTP session
    server.quit()
```

Despite the seemingly correct code execution, the emails are not being sent, and no error messages are received. I have verified the accuracy of the email credentials, checked the SMTP server and port, and confirmed that the email addresses are valid. Additionally, I've enabled two-factor authentication for the Gmail account and generated an App Password specifically for this script. Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

run the script, get email

Comment: Are they appearing in the sent folder of the sender? Are they appearing in the spam inbox of the receiver? And, `password` is the App Password right?

Comment: Hey, they are not aring in the sent folder of the sender, and not at the spam inbox of the receiver.
the App Password right? is right.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has very strict control over sending emails. You will have to enable "Less secure apps" in your settings, and even then I've had a good bit of trouble getting it to work.

Comment: so what can I do, is their any other SMTP provider? that enable it? about the less sevure app I did it but still it's not working.

Comment: You could try something like SendGrid